# exec не работает с set(команда sh)

Tags: c++, shell, процесс, exec, fork

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему в первом случае программа работает правильно, а во втором случае нет

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", "set", NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<char*> ARG(2);
    ARG[0] = "set";
    ARG[1] = nullptr;
    execvp(ARG[0], &ARG[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Хочу заметить, что если вместо "set" подставить "ls, echo" и другое, то второй пример работает корректно, в чем же исключительность "set" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница в том что `set` — это *встроенная команда оболочки* (*built-in command*) и её интерпретацией занимается сам `/bin/sh`, а `ls` — это отдельная программа `/bin/ls`.

`echo` — это особый случай: с одной стороны есть такая программа `/bin/echo`, а с другой, производительности ради, есть такая же команда оболочки. Так, например,

```
 execlp("sh", "sh", "-c", "echo --help", NULL);
```

выведет `--help`, а

```
 execlp("echo", "echo", "--help", NULL);
```

выдаст справку (по крайней мере для `echo` из GNU coreutils).

Определить, чем является команда, настоящей программой или чем-то ещё можно с помощью `type`:

```
$ type ls
ls — это псевдонимом для «ls --color=auto»
$ type -P ls
/bin/ls
$ type set
set — это встроенная команда bash
```

Список других встроенных команд (для `bash`) можно посмотреть соответственно в [`man bash`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=bash&category=8&russian=0#shell_builtin).

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как тогда в таком случае реализовать на пример программу, которая читает команды sh, и исполняет их в цикле (эмуляция shell на c++), как разделить встроенные и не встроенные команды ?

Comment: читаешь имя команды… проверяешь её по списку встроенных команд твоей оболочки, если она в списке, то исполняешь её… если нет, то запускаешь внешнюю команду... ничего хитрого тут нет: каждую такую команду нужно реализовывать самостоятельно… большинство встроенных команд влияют на поведение самой оболочки, так что их невозможно выполнить как какие-то внешние утилиты, так что для них придётся писать код… если это учебное задание, то, думаю, ни кто не ждёт от тебя, что ты напишешь полностью posix-совместимый-shell, так что все команды реализовывать не обязательно, но хотя бы `cd` сделать придётся…